# PHP no echo data when using exec

Tags: php, shell, command, echo

i have a problem using the exec function in php.
i try to echo parameteres back after executing a shell cmd. My problem is that after executing the shell cmd no parameters are sent back, if i edit the exec lines out everything works fine. here is the code:

```
    ...
    $command = 'avconv -i ' . 'path' . $targetFolder . '/' . $id . '.' . $fileParts['extension'] . ' -vcodec libx264 -r 24 -strict -2 -crf 24 ' . 'path' . $targetFolder . '/' . $id . '.mp4';
    exec($command);

    echo $var;
    echo $var2;
    echo $var3;
```

no data echoed back.

```
    ...
    echo $var;
    echo $var2;
    echo $var3;
```

data echoed back as supposed.

So where is the problem executing the shell cmd? do i have to call another function than exec?

When i write the echoes before the execution, they arent echoed either. The shell script works.

Comment: did u try using `echo exec($command);`?

Comment: i dont want to echo back the output of the command, the variables i echo back are other variables.

Comment: That was just for debugging. what output u get while echoing it might help.

Comment: i discovered that its a problem of a timeout. when my php script finish the processing within the timeout the data is echoed back correctly but when the timeout is reached (with the avconv video conversion command) no data is sent back. Is there any way i can swap out the shell command into another script that is processed seperatly? e.g. with the use of multithreading?

Comment: An obvious option is to try using the `sleep()` function to wake it up a couple of seconds later.

Comment: Well, i wrote another php script for exporting the converting process, now i call the convert script within my main script: exec('nohup php ./../cgi/convert.php ' . $input . ' ' . $output . ' > /dev/null 2>&1 &'); as a seperate process. all works fine now!

Comment: Post your own answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a timeout, set by the caller. It automatically returned after a concrete time and didnt send the echo data.

My solution was to create a seperate script containing the convert process that i executed as a daemon process.

```
exec('nohup php ./../cgi/convert.php ' . $input . ' ' . $output . ' > /dev/null 2>&1 &');
```